# Increase td size manually for each

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a bootstrap table in Angular. `<td>` takes equal available space and it aligns accordingly. But I need my first `<td>` to a bit longer than the default so that the text I type is fully visible. I hard-coded `width` and `max-width` values. But It's not responsive across all screen sizes.

[image: Example]

I need my `reason` and `time` textbox to be longer so that my text is visible.

Answer (score 0):

first of all some general questions:

1. Bootstrap version
2. HTML sourcecode

Possible Solutions:

1. assign colspan=2 to the columns "reason" and "time"
2. assign a fixed width to your checkbox columns so that the others will grow
3. did you try width: 100% and setting min-width?

There is not the one solution, there might be serveral was to achieve that.